# How can I extract the folder path from file path in Python?

Tags: python, file, path, directory, extract

I would like to get just the folder path from the full path to a file.

For example `T:\Data\DBDesign\DBDesign_93_v141b.mdb` and I would like to get just `T:\Data\DBDesign` (excluding the `\DBDesign_93_v141b.mdb`).

I have tried something like this:

```
existGDBPath = r'T:\Data\DBDesign\DBDesign_93_v141b.mdb'
wkspFldr = str(existGDBPath.split('\\')[0:-1])
print wkspFldr
```

but it gave me a result like this:

```
['T:', 'Data', 'DBDesign']
```

which is not the result that I require (being `T:\Data\DBDesign`).

Any ideas on how I can get the path to my file?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You were almost there with your use of the `split` function. You just needed to join the strings, like follows.

```
>>> import os
>>> '\\'.join(existGDBPath.split('\\')[0:-1])
'T:\\Data\\DBDesign'
```

Although, I would recommend using the `os.path.dirname` function to do this, you just need to pass the string, and it'll do the work for you. Since, you seem to be on windows, consider using the `abspath` function too. An example:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(existGDBPath))
'T:\\Data\\DBDesign'
```

If you want both the file name and the directory path after being split, you can use the `os.path.split` function which returns a tuple, as follows.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.split(os.path.abspath(existGDBPath))
('T:\\Data\\DBDesign', 'DBDesign_93_v141b.mdb')
```

Comment: `os.sep.join(existGDBPath.split(os.sep)[:-1]` looks prettier.

Comment: `'\\'.join()` is not portable, use `os.path.join()` instead

Comment: Using str methods `split` and `join` is not portable (think `/` on *nix).  `os.path` has all methods you need.

Answer (score 132):

**WITH PATHLIB MODULE (UPDATED ANSWER)**

One should consider using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for new development.  It is in the stdlib for Python3.4, but [available on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib/) for earlier versions.  This library provides a more object-orented method to manipulate paths `<opinion>` and is much easier read and program with `</opinion>`.

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> existGDBPath = pathlib.Path(r'T:\Data\DBDesign\DBDesign_93_v141b.mdb')
>>> wkspFldr = existGDBPath.parent
>>> print wkspFldr
Path('T:\Data\DBDesign')
```

**WITH OS MODULE**

Use the [os.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module:

```
>>> import os
>>> existGDBPath = r'T:\Data\DBDesign\DBDesign_93_v141b.mdb'
>>> wkspFldr = os.path.dirname(existGDBPath)
>>> print wkspFldr 
'T:\Data\DBDesign'
```

You can go ahead and assume that if you need to do some sort of filename manipulation it's already been implemented in `os.path`.  If not, you'll still probably need to use this module as the building block.

Comment: `Path().parent` what I was looking for!

Comment: Marked-up simply because you stuck <opinion /> in tags!

Answer (score 75):

The built-in submodule [os.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) has a function for that very task.

```
import os
os.path.dirname('T:\Data\DBDesign\DBDesign_93_v141b.mdb')
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code:

```
import os
existGDBPath = r'T:\Data\DBDesign\DBDesign_93_v141b.mdb'
wkspFldr = os.path.dirname(existGDBPath)
print wkspFldr # T:\Data\DBDesign
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my little utility helper for splitting paths int file, path tokens:

```
import os    
# usage: file, path = splitPath(s)
def splitPath(s):
    f = os.path.basename(s)
    p = s[:-(len(f))-1]
    return f, p
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone trying to do this in the ESRI GIS Table field calculator interface can do this with the **Python parser**:

PathToContainingFolder =

```
"\\".join(!FullFilePathWithFileName!.split("\\")[0:-1])
```

so that

\Users\me\Desktop\New folder\file.txt

becomes

\Users\me\Desktop\New folder

Answer (score 0):

I use this to change the current working directory to a folder;

```
from os import chdir
from os.path import realpath
from os.path import dirname

chdir(realpath(dirname(argv[0])))
```

- chdir changes the working directory. I doubt you'll need this.
- realpath follows symlinks.
- dirname returns just the path
- argv is the command line used to execute the program