# Delete Specific Part Of A String

Tags: python, string, substring

I want to delete the part after the last `'/'` of a string in this following way:

```
str = "live/1374385.jpg"
formated_str = "live/"
```

or

```
str = "live/examples/myfiles.png"
formated_str = "live/examples/"
```

**I have tried this so far ( working )**

```
import re
for i in re.findall('(.*?)/',str):
    j += i
    j += '/'
```

Output :

`live/` or `live/examples/`

I am a beginner to python so just curious is there any other way to do that .

Comment: You might want to check [How to get everything after last slash in a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253803/how-to-get-everything-after-last-slash-in-a-url)

Comment: no opposite of it before the last slash of the url

Comment: I am pretty sure you can find the answer by tweaking the accepted answer a bit.

Comment: @ProFan - Is [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33372054/get-folder-name-of-the-file-in-python) marked as duplicated helpful for you? 
Because I think it is a bit different.

Comment: no it's not actually because I wanted to get the URL directory which can't be done using `os.path.dirname`

Comment: _Why_ can't it be done with `os.path.dirname`? It seems to work perfectly. Specify why it's unsuitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/string-methods.html):

```
str = "live/1374385.jpg"
print (str.rsplit('/', 1)[0] + '/')
live/

str = "live/examples/myfiles.png"
print (str.rsplit('/', 1)[0] + '/')
live/examples/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`.rindex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rindex) string method:

```
s = 'live/examples/myfiles.png'
s[:s.rindex('/')+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def removePart(_str1):
    return "/".join(_str1.split("/")[:-1])+"/"

def main():
    print removePart("live/1374385.jpg")
    print removePart("live/examples/myfiles.png")

main()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.