# Adding folder name as a prefix to the file's name

Tags: python, filenames

I am creating files dynamically in different folders, like so:

```py
curr_dir = "/a/b/c"
filename = os.path.join(curr_dir, 'file.text')
```

Which gives me:

```
"/a/b/c/file.text"
```

But because I am creating files with the same name in many folders, I want to distinguish them by adding the folder's name as a prefix, to get:

```
"a/b/c/c_file.text"
```

How can I get that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get folder name of the file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33372054/get-folder-name-of-the-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
texfile = os.path.join(curr_dir, 'all_files.tex')
```

only concatenates the current directory path to your filename.

You should have something like:

```
texfile = os.path.join(curr_dir, os.path.basename(curr_dir)+'_all_files.tex')
```

Comment: your edit does not work. Gives --> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) package instead:

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path()
WindowsPath('.')

>>> Path().absolute()
WindowsPath('C:/Users/p00200284/test')

>>> Path().absolute().parent
WindowsPath('C:/Users/p00200284')

>>> Path().absolute().parent / "all_files.tex"
WindowsPath('C:/Users/p00200284/all_files.tex')

>>> str(Path().absolute().parent / "all_files.tex")
'C:\\Users\\p00200284\\all_files.tex'

>>> Path().absolute().parent.name
'p00200284'

>>> f"{Path().absolute().parent.name}_all_files.tex"
'p00200284_all_files.tex'

>>> parent_dir = Path().absolute().parent
>>> parent_dir / f"{Path().absolute().parent.name}_all_files.tex"
WindowsPath('C:/Users/p00200284/p00200284_all_files.tex')
```

Comment: well you already saved `parent_dir` so you can just do `parent_dir / f"{parent_dir.name}_all_files.tex"`

Comment: Also note that the `parent` is not necessary. OP wants to create the file in the given directory, with its name as the prefix