# Extract folder structure from a list of given files in python

Tags: python, automation

I have multiple files and I need to extract the folder from its path.

folder1/folder2/templates/xyz.yaml

folder1/folderx/templates/abc.yaml

How can i extract folder2 and folderx in python.

Comment: If they are stored as strings, and for example called `path`, then you can do `path.split('/')[1]`.

Comment: Perhaps the `os.path.dirname()` or `os.path.split()` functions may be of use. An advantage is that it’s portable, whereas using the `str.split()` function is not always guaranteed to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get folder name of the file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33372054/get-folder-name-of-the-file-in-python)

Comment: i modified a little and made like this:      import os
print( f"Full Path    :{diff}" )
nmFolders = diff.split( os.path.sep )
print( "List of Folders:", nmFolders )
print( f"Program Name :{nmFolders[-1]}" )
print( f"Folder Name  :{nmFolders[-2]}" )
print( f"Folder Parent:{nmFolders[-3]}" ) This works well for single file, But what if i have multiple files which i need to iterate through.

Comment: @Rishi - Please update the **question** accordingly, with input examples *and* the expected output.

Comment: i found out a way to do it with path.split("\n") and str.split(os.path.sep).